# How can I allow a method to accept either a string or int?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, methods

Using C# 4.0, is there a way to allow a method (without creating an overload) to accept a string or an int and then allow me to detect what type was passed in?

Comment: That's exactly the use for which overloaded methods are intended. Why are you opposed to using them?

Comment: Agree with Cody. It CAN be done, but it can't be done i a very pretty way. Both me and Cody have two suggestions below, but it is not a very good way of doing it, really.

Comment: Thanks Cody.  I am not opposed to them, I just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing a simple, new feature in 4.0 that would allow this.  Since it is now possible to do optional and named types I thought perhaps there was a new clean way to do this.  Thanks!

Comment: @user390480: Not really. There are alternatives, but there's no better way. It intrigues me that you think of method overloading as unclean or less than optimal in any way. I honestly think it's one of the *coolest* language features of all time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since you're using C# 4.0, you can write a [generic method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx). For example:

```
void MyMethod<T>(T param)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
    {
        // the object is an int
    }
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
    {
        // the object is a string
    }
}
```

But you should very seriously consider whether or not this is a good idea. The above example is a bit of a code smell. In fact, the whole point of generics is to be *generic*. If you have to special-case your code depending on the type of the object passed in, that's a sign you should be using overloading instead. That way, each method overload handles its unique case. I can't imagine any disadvantage to doing so.

Comment: +1 I agree with Cody. Please use overloads if it is possible!

Comment: Agree with the smell around the example; two overloads are better here.

Comment: I'd suggest posting a good example before a bad one. Remember some people (especially those who understand code more than English) will just grab the example and use it as opposed to reading the important text that this probably isn't a good idea. To be honest for this horrific example you don't even need generics, you could just make the parameter an object. ugh.

Comment: @Quibblesome: The "good" example is method overloading. I would have posted that, except the question *specifically* stated that was not an option. As much as some people might grab the code without looking, others would have downvoted by answer without looking, given the caveat in the question had I posted an example of overloading. Furthermore, making the parameter an `object` is **not** a better solution. Using generics is the better option because it alleviates the performance penalty incurred by boxing an `int` into an `object` and vice versa.

Comment: Lets be honest, generics or an object are both crap solutions. Generics being slightly less crap for performance reasons. Still, we don't know how often the method is called so to bring up performance is somewhat premature. I missed the bit in the original question where stated he didn't want to use overloading, sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can! An example of this is

```
    public void MyMethod(object o)
    {
        if (o.GetType() == typeof(string))
        {
            //Do something if string
        }
        else if (o.GetType() == typeof(int))
        {
            // Do something else
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could do it like this, but that imposes a performance penalty because the `int` is boxed into an `object`. Since the asker is using C# 4.0, generics are a much better option.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap *string* and *int* in some wrapper with marker interface and pass them to a method.

Something like this

```
interface IMyWrapper<T> { T Value {get; }}
public class StringWrapper: IMyWrapper<string> { ... }
public class IntWrapper: IMyWrapper<int> { ... }

void MyMethod<T>(IMyWrapper<T> wrapper)
{
}
```

Comment: Why in the world would you do that instead of writing a generic method?

Comment: Code Gray, if you can show me a good example how can I restrict a generic method to *int* and *double* only without throwing exception in runtime then I wouldn't .

Comment: I'm not really sure why a run-time exception would be a problem. If you *did* pass a disallowed type to the method in question, you would *want to* catch that during debugging, so a run-time exception seems ideal. That case would be a problem in your code. It's *exceptionally* rare that the end user is dynamically invoking your method and specifying an arbitrary data type. And even if they are, what happens in your scenario? They still get a run-time error: no method signature compatible with the specified arguments.

Comment: How in the world should I understand what I'm allowed to pass to *void MyMethod<T>(T param)* before I will be hit by exception? Is *float* a good choise? How about *double* or *MyStruct* ?  Should I test it with every other type from my library? In my case you have a clear contract that will be verified in complie time and there is almost no way for you to break this contract unless *IMyWrapper* is exposed as a part of API.

Comment: @Andrei: It tells you in the documentation included with the API. Of course, if you refuse to read (or write) documentation and do it anyway, yes, you'll get an exception. You can immediately fix your code. Additionally, since we're talking about C# 4.0 in the question, you can use code contracts, e.g.: `Contract.Requires(typeof(T) == typeof(string))`

Comment: @Cody Gray, it becomes too complicated. Obliratory documentation + extra library + code to deal with possible exception vs. just a simple complie-time check. I would prefer the 2nd approach and I would always prefer the design where I can prevent user from misuse of the API trather that explain the possible outcome of misuse in documentation.

Comment: Actually, how is this going to work?  MyMethod is taking in a plain IMyMarker but IMyMarker is generic.

Answer (score 0):

I would think a method overload would be a straightforward solution, if you want to stay away from stuff like reflection or checking types.

```
public void MethodName(string foo)
{
     int bar = 0;
     if(int.tryparse(foo))
        return MethodName(bar);//calls int overload
}
```